# Querying Active Records and Foreign Key Help [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I know there are probably many different ways to do this, but using http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html, I have been unable to find the best way that works for me.

I am making a forum using RoR, and I came across a problem when deleting posts from topics.

Each Topic has many posts. Each post has one topic.

When you post in the topic, it updates the topic table with who last posted and the time. However, when you delete a post, it keeps the old data of the post.

When I delete a post, I need to update the topic table with the previous post's data.

I know after deleting, I need to query all the posts in a topic, find the last one and use its data to update the topic.

How do I do that though?

The Query would be something like

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (topic_id = topic.id) ORDER BY id DESC

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

def create  
  @post = Post.new(
    :content => params[:post][:content], 
    :topic_id => params[:post][:topic_id], 
    :user_id => current_user.id)  

  if @post.save  
    @topic = Topic.find(@post.topic_id)  
    @topic.update_attributes(
      :last_poster_id => current_user.id, 
      :last_post_at => Time.now)  
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."  
    redirect_to "/topics/#{@post.topic_id}"  
  else  
    render :action => 'new'  
  end  
end  

def update  
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])  
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post].permit!) 
    @topic = Topic.find(@post.topic_id)  
    @topic.update_attributes(:last_poster_id => current_user.id, :last_post_at => Time.now)  
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated post."  
    redirect_to @post  
  else  
    render :action => 'edit'  
  end  
end  

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]) 

    @post.destroy

    **# WHAT QUERY STATEMENT GOES HERE** 

    @topic.update_attributes(
      :last_poster_id => @post.user_id, 
      :last_post_at => @post.created_at)  
      redirect_to "/topics/#{@post.topic_id}"

  end
end
```

Comment: do you want to use information of a previous post which you are deleted to update for topic ? example if your topic has two post: A, B, then when you delete post B, topic will be update with info of post A ?

Comment: Yes. I would want the topic to be updated with info from post A if you delete post B

Comment: please try code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @topic = @post.topic
  @post.destroy
  last_post = @topic.reload.posts.last
  @topic.update_attributes(last_poster_id: last_post.user_id, last_post_at: last_post.created_at)
  redirect_to @topic
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know reload was an option. It works perfectly.